# VBA syntax: Workbooks.Item(1).Name

Tags: vba, excel, syntax

I know, VBA Syntax is `object.property` or `object.method`.

But `Workbooks.Item(1).Name` is `object.property.property`, can it be available to code?

I also know that the `Workbooks` collection has `Item` property, `Count` property, `Creator` property.

What property belongs to `Name` at `Workbooks.Item(1).Name`?

Comment: There are few cases where `Item` is necessary.  `Workbooks(1).Name` is fine.  Objects can contain objects so yes you can have a string of references: `Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Font.Bold = True`

Comment: @TonyDallimore it's useful to note that `Workbooks(1).Name` is fine because `Item` is the default property of the `Workbooks` collection. That particular shortcut only works in VBA.

Comment: @RubberDuck There are so many differences between VBA and other languages that I rarely think it worth mentioning if a feature is unique to VBA.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I was thinking of VB.Net in particular. I think it's similar enough that it was worth mentioning that the syntax there is different. I also think it's worth mentioning because VBA is basically the *only* place the short-cutted syntax still works.

Comment: @RubberDuck  have never used `Item` when accessing Excel from VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Useful documentation reading order for deciphering the meaning of `Workbooks.Item(1).Name` (other then pressing F1 with cursor blinking inside the unknown word in the macro editor) would be:

1. [MSDN: Excel 2013 developer reference → Workbooks Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841074.aspx)

   > A collection of all the Workbook objects...
2. [MSDN: Excel 2013 developer reference → Workbooks.Item Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196016.aspx)

   > Returns a single object from a collection
3. [MSDN: Excel 2013 developer reference → Workbook.Name Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820899.aspx)

   > Returns a String value that represents the name of the object

Answer (score 0):

If you try it, you'll see that it is indeed available and valid syntax. Let's examine `Workbooks.Item(1).Name` a little bit and break it down to see why that is.

- `Workbooks` is a collection object. (A special one, but that's not the point.)
- `Item` is a method that returns a `Workbook` object.

So, calling `Debug.Print Workbooks.Item(1).Name` is equivalent to this code.

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Item(1)
Debug.Print book.Name
```

This is known as "Method Chaining" and hinges on the fact that one method here returns an object that has methods/properties of it's own.